# Return JSON when an Unhandled error 500 exception is thrown

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

If there's an unhandled server error 500 in ASP.NET MVC, the server returns a HTML page like this:

[image]

**Question:** is it possible to configure the application so that it returns a JSON with the same information instead of the above HTML?

eg:

```
   {
        Title:'Maximum request length exceeded',
        Description:'An unhandled eception .....',
        ...etc
   }
```

Comment: You can create your own custom error page and return whatever you like

Comment: but i don't wanna lose the things are are shown in here: title, exception details, source error, stack trace, etc....

Answer (score 0):

you need to catch the error somehwere appropriate [i suggest use custom error filter on the controller for example that inherits from HandleErrorAttribute], and override OnException method, from there you can check if it is Ajax, then do something else, here is a snippet that i wrote before (not clean yet) 
and dont forget to set the status code!

```
 if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            JsonResultObject result = new JsonResultObject();
            result.Success = false;
            string message = ("Common.WeAreFixing" + " , #" + errorLog.Id.ToString("00000"));
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsLocal)
            {
                message = filterContext.Exception.Message + Environment.NewLine + "st: " +
                          (filterContext.Exception.StackTrace ?? "");
            }
            result.AlertMessage = new Alert(message, Alert.Type.Error);

            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            filterContext.Result = new JsonDotNetResult()
            {
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                Data = result
            };
            filterContext.HttpContext.Items["ErrorNumber"] = errorLog.Id.ToString("00000");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Within exceptions there is sensitive information including stack details that should not be leaked to the consumer however as you are showing the error screen i am presuming that this is running in a debug environment and that is not an issue.

Also in a non debug environment the exception details may be stripped out of the response so ideally you should form a custom message of Json format that is based off that exception and then log the original stack details so you can handle the issue at a later date.

Something like the below should get you started:

```
    try
    {
        // do some work
    }
    catch (ExplicitException ex)
    {
        // Log the exception(ex);

        var message = "Error Doing Work");
        return Json(new { status = "Error", message });
    }
}
```